# String to unique decimal

Tags: string, unicode, decimal, unique, crc32

I have strings that are in the format (0-9)(A-Z)(A-Z)(A-Z)(A-Z) e.g. 0AAAA or 7ZHSK etc

I want a platform independent way to convert this to a unique decimal.

I have tried crc32 which is very close to what I want and I have tested that there are no collisions with all the 4,569,760 possible combinations.

My problem is crc32 outputs a different result on a 32bit machine and a 64bit machine,

Is there anything similar that will so the job? I need to use standard functions that would be available in multiple languages, so no custom functions.

Edit:
Here is an example of code to run at these two locations:

```
echo crc32('1AAAA');
```

http://www.writephponline.com

```
output = -534072890
```

http://phptester.net

```
output = 3760894406
```

Comment: Which CRC implementation is this? Surely CRC only makes sense if it behaves the same across all platforms.

Comment: @biziclop I noticed this when using PHP on different systems

Comment: If the CRC is different on the machines, then there is a bug in your implementation. In any case, a CRC-32 for this application is silly, as the data can be completely encoded in less than 32 bits.

Comment: @MarkAdler please see edited question I have added examples showing different systems returning different results for the same function

Comment: Those are the same 32-bit value, printed as signed in one case and unsigned in the other.

Comment: @MarkAdler how do I ensure they are always unsigned regardless of the system?

Comment: You should simply not care if it is signed or unsigned. All that you should care about is that you compare them properly. When you construct the CRC from four bytes in the stream using the same integer type in that same language, then it will be respectively signed or unsigned as well and will compare as equal with the computed CRC.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use place-value semantics? The result only requires 23 bits, so it fits perfectly into a standard integral type:

```
#include <cinttypes>
#include <string>

std::uint32_t to_int(std::string const & s)
{
    return
       (s[4] - 'A') * 1 +
       (s[3] - 'A') * 26 +
       (s[2] - 'A') * 26*26 +
       (s[1] - 'A') * 26*26*26 +
       (s[0] - '0') * 26*26*26*26;
}
```

(This assumes that your string encoding contains all the capital letter characters in a contiguous sequence, e.g. like UTF-8.)